# Technical error of measurement (TEM) for 3 or more participants

Tags: r

I need to implement this formula into an R function. To my surprise there were no R packages with a TEM function for 3 or more participants. Could someone help me out?

[image: TEM]

Comment: it's not clear the index over which the outer sum runs. the inner sum runs over `n`?

Comment: How do you have your data stored?

Comment: this link to the paper he is referring to, found at ``henge.bioanth.cam.ac.uk/nmt_pubs/goto_nmt_jpa_2007.pdf`` will probably help those attempting to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
# M : data frame of different measurements
tem <- function(M) {
    nrows <- nrow(M)
    ncols <- ncol(M)
    sqrt(sum(apply(M,1,function(x) sum(x^2) - sum(x)^2/ncols))/(nrows*(ncols-1)))
}
```

Here's an example

```
child_data <- data.frame(
    height_a=c(64.50,71.00,58.00,58.00,70.50,69.00,63.00,65.00,62.00,68.00),
    height_b=c(64.00,71.50,59.00,58.00,71.50,67.50,64.00,64.50,62.00,68.00)
)

tem(child_data)
# 0.5477
```

this is the figure presented in the paper you referenced.

Then, for example (three columns)

```
child_data$height_c <- c(63.5,71.3,59.0,58.5,71.4,67.4,64.2,64.50,62.5,67.5)
tem(child_data)
# 0.5
```

Comment: Could you help me with implementing the other TEM formula as well? The one on page 2 for intra-observer error.

Comment: I'm not sure what formula you are referring to?

Comment: [formula link](http://i.imgur.com/a0NX4ZY.png)

It's the simpler version of TEM for intra-observer error.

Comment: this formula will work for that case. (for example, ``tem(child_data) # 0.5477`` above)

Comment: So I can substitute K/columns for either # of participants or a single participants repeated measurements?