Coefficient of reliability in R
I am trying to calculate the coeffinicent of reliability in R. Its values should be from 0 to 1, however I am consistently hitting values way out of this range.
I am calculating it on the following data (dataDocasky):
m1  m2
171.3428819 213.1527819
133.9369251 112.9075057
113.6293344 133.9437121
118.0038635 120.0285206
147.6831421 150.8048938
60.73677582 39.94156928
94.13120567 104.8376963
89.39633733 93.43794579
36.91675999 37.33705773
81.46137139 94.90522423

To calculate CR, I am supposed to use the following equation:
CR = 1 - (TEM^2/sd^2) * 100
TEM stands for Technical error of measurement, and I have calculated it according to the equation and function written here

TEM <- function(df, col1, col2){
  sqrt(((sum(df[, col1] - df[, col2])^2)) / 2 * nrow(df))
}

TEM_docasky <- TEM(dataDocasky,  "m1", "m2"); TEM_docasky


I have calculated the sd(standart deviation) as follows:
sd_Docasky <- sd(as.matrix(dataDocasky)); sd_Docasky
And using all those equations I then calculated CR with the following:
cr_Docasky <- 1 - ((TEM_docasky^2 / sd_Docasky^2) * 100); cr_Docasky
However, this will give me the result of CR: -717.0229 which... is way out of the 0-1 range.
Can anyone see where I have made the mistake that is throwing my result off?
My calculated values are
TEM: 120.8781
sd: 45.11057
CR: -717.0229
Thank you!

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041102/technical-error-of-measurement-tem-for-3-or-more-participants

your function for TEM is not quite correct. It appears to me you are summing the differences, and then squaring, but you should be squaring the differences and then summing.
An alternative TEM function is:
TEM <- function(x,y) sqrt( sum((x-y)^2)/(2*length(x)))
TEM(df$m1, df$m2)

[1] 12.96368


Therefore, you can proceed with your calculation as follows:
cr <- function(x,y) { tem = TEM(x,y); 1-tem^2/var(c(x,y))}
cr(df$m1, df$m2)

Output:
0.9174152


Thank you for the help with the TEM, I should have checked out the function code better. Could I just ask about the corrections you have done to the CR formula? I am not really sure how sd squared translates to var(c(x,y)).

var() is variance (i.e sd squared). You will note that as.matrix(df) |> sd() is equal to var(c(df$m1, df$m2)) |> sqrt()
